# Coordinate systems with common start

Tags: linear-algebra, euclidean-geometry, 3d

Given two coordinate systems $0xyz,0XYZ$ with common starting point $0$. Are there points in $\Bbb R^3$ besides $0$ that preserve their coordinates as to both these systems? My attempt:

We want $$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
X=x=a_{11}x+a_{12}y+a_{13}z \\ 
Y=y=a_{21}x+a_{22}y+a_{23}z \\ 
Z=z=a_{31}x+a_{32}y+a_{33}z
\end{array}
\right. 
$$
$$\iff
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
(a_{11}-1)x+a_{12}y+a_{13}z=0 \\ 
a_{21}x+(a_{22}-1)y+a_{23}z=0 \\ 
a_{31}x+a_{32}y+(a_{33}-1)z=0
\end{array}
\right. 
$$
But since it is homogeneous then it has the trivial solution $\iff$ $det(A)\ne0$, where $A$ is the coefficients matrix.
So the answer is no?

EDIT:

If $det(A)=0$ then the transformation may fix points, so the answer is yes there are coordinate system changes that do not affect points. Is this correct?

Comment: Surely the answer depends on the particular transformation? For example, isn't $(x,y,z)\mapsto(x,y,2z)$ a map that fixes points of the form $(x,y,0)$?

Comment: @MPW But isn't this the same coordinate system?

Comment: No, I've changed the scale on one axis, right? So, for example, if the original system measures units in inches on each axis, but the new system measures units on the $z$-axis in centimeters, the the point with coordinates $(1,1,1)$ in the old system would have coordinates $(1,1,2.54)$ in the new system. But the point $(1,1,0)$ in the old system would also have coordinates $(1,1,0)$ in the new system.

Comment: @MPW Okay, I guess this works. Thanks.